why is my discord bot asking for the same folder twice?
trying to make a private discord bot for personal tools like ban, kick. user info... but when i try to launch the bot i get this error:
edit:
PS D:\Rubytoolbot> node index.js 
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
D:\Rubytoolbot\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:9
    return (connectionString.startsWith('mongodb://') ||
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at connectionStringHasValidScheme (D:\Rubytoolbot\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:9:30)
    at new ConnectionString (D:\Rubytoolbot\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:85:34)
    at parseOptions (D:\Rubytoolbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:192:17)
    at new MongoClient (D:\Rubytoolbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:52:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Rubytoolbot\index.js:79:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)

Node.js v21.7.2

require('dotenv').config({ path: './Rubytoolbot/.env' }) //uses custom location
const fs = require("fs");
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require("discord.js");
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb'); // Import MongoClient from mongodb package
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

// MongoDB configuration
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

// When the bot is added to a new server
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
  console.log(`Added to guild: ${guild.name} (ID: ${guild.id})`);

  try {
    await mongoClient.connect();
    const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Change to your desired database name
    const collection = database.collection('guilds');

    // Insert the guild ID and name into the collection
    await collection.insertOne({ guildId: guild.id, guildName: guild.name });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding guild to MongoDB:", error);
  } finally {
    await mongoClient.close();
  }
});

// When the bot is removed from a server
client.on("guildDelete", async (guild) => {
  console.log(`Removed from guild: ${guild.name} (ID: ${guild.id})`);

  try {
    await mongoClient.connect();
    const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Change to your desired database name
    const collection = database.collection('guilds');

    // Remove the guild ID from the collection
    await collection.deleteOne({ guildId: guild.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error removing guild from MongoDB:", error);
  } finally {
    await mongoClient.close();
  }
});

tried changing "require("dotenv").config();" on the top of index.js to: require('dotenv').config({ path: './Rubytoolbot/.env' }) //uses custom location but getting the same result.  i expect it to work without problems. the .env file is in the same folder as index.js

Is the code you gave running in the Rubytoolbot directory? If so, you would simply need to change ./Rubytoolbot/commands to ./commands.
The ./ portion of the file path implies the current directory, by writing ./Rubytoolbot/commands you're essentially looking in the ./Rubytoolbot/Rubytoolbot/commands directory, which doesn't exist.

looks like that helped thanks. but a new error occured.

It looks like you have the same issue here. Try require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' }). That said, you're not showing the part where you define connectionString, so I can't say for certain if that fixes the whole issue.

If the original problem was resolved by this answer, then it should be accepted as such. A new error means a new question should be opened rather than continuing to edit and move the goal post on this one
